# GDB locking up in Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx)

Tags: gdb, ubuntu-10.04

Since I upgraded my OS to Ubuntu 10.04, I'm experiencing serious problems with GDB. Basically, every time I try to auto-complete using TAB, the process becomes unresponsive for several seconds, or forever. I have to kill gdb and lose my session.

The same happens if I accidentally try to print a variable that isn't in scope or doesn't exist (which is easy to do by accident).

Anyone else see this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did a little poking around and it seems that 7.1 has issues (my particular one was the inability to print variables without locking up).  IIRC it had to do w/ large footprint binaries.  Can't seem to find the link...